# Which is the best for this query, "Inner join" or "Where"

Tags: sql, t-sql, optimization

I have this SQL query

```
SELECT t.id AS taskid,
       STUFF(
           (
               SELECT ',' + x.tID
               FROM   (
                          SELECT CAST(id AS VARCHAR(200)) AS tid
                          FROM CRSTask c WHERE c.ParentTask = 
                          7562 -- comment this line
                      ) x
                      FOR XML PATH('')
           ),
           1,
           1,
           ''
       ) AS strIDS
FROM   CRSTask t
WHERE t.ParentTask IS NULL
AND t.id = 7562 -- comment this line
```

the result of this query will be:

```
 id          strIDS  
7562    7615,7616,7617,7618,7619,7620,7621,7631,7632,123
```

This is good, but when I tried to replace the `strIDS` with its names from another table it takes alot of time.

e.g. 123 [the last id in strIDS] is a taskID from CRSTask, has a relation ont-to-one to CRSTaskReceiver
and taskReceiver has a relation one-to-one to Portal_Users_View(id,userName)
-I need to replace 123 with its equivalent userName
-I made it using Joins .. it take a lot of time, also using Where between tables take alot of time

Comment: You need to show us your amended query. And the structure of the tables you are trying to join on.

Comment: SELECT t.id AS taskid,STUFF( ( SELECT ',' + x.ArabicName
               FROM   ( SELECT ArabicName
FROM Portal_Users_View
WHERE ID IN (SELECT CRSTaskReceiver.ReceiverID
                                       FROM   CRSTaskReceiver
                                       WHERE  CRSTaskReceiver.CRSTaskID IN /*305*/
(SELECT  CAST(id AS VARCHAR(200)) AS tid
FROM   CRSTask c
WHERE  c.ParentTask = 7562
))
) x
FOR XML PATH('')
),
1,
1,
           ''
) AS strIDS
FROM   CRSTask t
WHERE t.ParentTask IS NULL
AND t.id = 7562

Comment: Edit your post, not in the comment box.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question : in my opinion JOINs are better in 99% of the cases as they show the underlying data-model more clearly. This makes it easier to maintain the code AND the query optimizer also has an easier time to come up with a decent query-plan.

I'm not a big fan of UDF's, but in this case it might be the easiest way to solve your problem as aggregating a string isn't natively supported by MSSQL:

```
-- create User Defined Function to fetch list of names for given taskid
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_names_from_taskid ( @taskid int )
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @result nvarchar(max)
        SELECT @result = ''

        SELECT @result = @result 
                       +  Portal_Users_View.ArabicName + ','
          FROM Portal_Users_View 
          JOIN CRSTaskReceiver 
            ON CRSTaskReceiver.ReceiverID = Portal_Users_View.ID
          JOIN CRSTask c 
            ON CAST(c.id AS VARCHAR(200)) = CRSTaskReceiver.CRSTaskID -- cast really necessary?
           AND c.ParentTask = @taskid 

        -- strip last comma (if present)
        SELECT @result = (CASE WHEN Right(@result, 1) = ',' THEN Left(@result, Len(@result) - 1) ELSE @result END)

        Return(@result)
    END

GO

-- usage    
SELECT taskid    = t.id,
       nameslist = dbo.fn_names_from_taskid (t.id)
  INTO #test
 WHERE id = 7652
```

PS: I tried to interpret your datamodel from the code above, you'll need to double-check it though!

PS: is the Cast() really necessary ? I would assume all id fields to be stored as int ?!? If so (and with the right indexes) those joins should be 'blazingly fast', but with the Cast() in there the server can't use its indexes properly and you might have the weirdest behavior performance-wise.